# AFnetworking is not uploading image to server

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, afnetworking

Hello i am new to afnetworking, i want to upload image at server path from ios sdk. below is code for afnetworking,

```
NSData *imageToUpload = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(selectedImageView.image, 90);
AFHTTPClient *client= [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.100//smart_attendance/api/employeeImage.php"]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"employee_images/large/" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData: imageToUpload name:@"file" fileName:@"temp.jpeg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
}];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSString *response = [operation responseString];
    NSLog(@"response: [%@]",response);
   // [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    //[MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    if([operation.response statusCode] == 403){
        NSLog(@"Upload Failed");
        return;
    }
    NSLog(@"error: %@", [operation error]);

}];

[operation start];
```

SERVER RESPONSE IS

```
 AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=<NSMutableURLRequest   
http://192.168.0.102/trackingwebsite/tree_images/large/>,  
NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.0.102/trackingwebsite/tree_images/large/, 
NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 404, 
AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x98671e0>}
```

Comment: what response or error did you get?

Comment: Sometimes its saying all parameter are not passed and if i chaged file path then some times its saying url not found on this server

Comment: I think your url construction was strange, how about have a look at this document's URL Construction Section: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.3.1/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html .You should check if your base url and path were right

Comment: plase see the response

Comment: i am not getting how we can constrcy correct url and its path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this for url.

```
 NSString *imgUrl=[imageURLString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:imgUrl];
```

Also your path string is not proper i guess.
Hope that helps.

welll i am using this way and its working fine.

```
 NSString* imageName = @"_image.png";

[[AFAPIClient sharedClient]initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BaseUrl]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFAPIClient sharedClient] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",BaseUrl,sign_up.php] parameters:dict constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData)
                                {
                                    [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImagePNGRepresentation([dict objectForKey:@"image"]) name:@"image" fileName:imageName mimeType:@"image/png"];
                                }];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {

 }
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {

 }];    
[[AFAPIClient sharedClient]enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
[operation release];
```

edited

```
AFHTTPClient *client= [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL     URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.100/smart_attendance/api/employeeImage.php"]];
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"http://192.168.0.100/smart_attendance/api/employeeImage.php" 
parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) { 
[formData appendPartWithFileData:imageToUpload name:@"file" fileName:@"temp.jpeg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];

 }];
```

Comment: your path is the service url you are hitting.

Comment: means web service URL ??

Comment: yes just like yours http://192.168.0.100//smart_attendance/api/employeeImage.php   
have a try.

Comment: AFHTTPClient *client= [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.100/smart_attendance/api/employeeImage.php/"]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"employee_images/large" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageToUpload name:@"file" fileName:@"temp.jpeg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    }];

Comment: AFHTTPClient *client= [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.100/smart_attendance/api/employeeImage.php/"]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"http://192.168.0.100/smart_attendance/api/employeeImage.php/"] parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageToUpload name:@"file" fileName:@"temp.jpeg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    }];

Comment: try out my edited answer .Also check that you are passinf the exact key at "name" key which is in your case "file" .